# How to do multi-agent modeling?

Tags: simulation, modeling

There are tons of examples here:

http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/topic.html?topic=multi-agent+modeling&limit=20

But I been unable to find a good guide explaining what is the recommended approach to build such a simulation...

Concretely, I am looking for a link to Mathematica help or a book like [https://www.amazon.com/An-Introduction-Agent-Based-Modeling-Engineered/dp/0262731894](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0262731894) but built around Mathematica instead of built around NetLogo... Is there a single one?

Comment: Look for work by Charles Macal e.g. in library.wolfram.com. I believe this came up recently on MSE but I cannot locate a link. "Agent-based modeling and simulation" is one article but there may be others as well.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/search/?search_results=1&search_person_id=5107 points me to http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/5767/ which it seems to delegate agents to http://repast.sourceforge.net/. What I want to know is how to build this kind of thing with pure Wolfram language (as in the CDF examples linked).

Comment: Mmm, maybe you mean http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Conferences/6513/ ....

Comment: Certainly that would be one. I think there may be others by Macal and perhaps coauthors. Not necessarily at library.w.c, I think some of that relevant work is available at an Argonne site.

Comment: Perhaps the books by Richard J Gaylord et al. Computer Simulations with Mathematica, and Modeling Nature: Cellular Automata Simulations with Mathematica.

Comment: You should know that Cellular Automaton not equals with Multi-Agents.